# Javascript. Почему не срабатывает else?

Tags: javascript, if

Почему не срабатывает else? В коде написано, что если я ввожу что-то кроме 'Edge', 'Chrome' 'Firefox' 'Safari' 'Opera', то должно выходить сообщение 'We hope that this page looks ok!'.

Но выходит только сообщение 'Okay we support these browsers too'

```
let browser = prompt('which browser do you use?', '')

  if (browser == 'Edge') {
    alert( "You've got the Edge!" );
  } else if (browser == 'Chrome' || 'Firefox' || 'Safari' || 'Opera') {
    alert( 'Okay we support these browsers too' )
  } else {
      alert( 'We hope that this page looks ok!' )
  }
```

Comment: (browser == 'Chrome' || 'Firefox' || 'Safari' || 'Opera') - это не так работает. Вам в данном случае нужно проверять каждое слово. (browser == 'Chrome' || browser == 'Firefox' ... )

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Нужно проверять каждое слово `(browser == 'Chrome' || browser == 'Firefox' ...)` или попроще: проверить вхождение в массив:

```
if (['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Safari', 'Opera'].includes(browser)) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать так:

```
let browser = prompt('which browser do you use?', '')

if (browser == 'Edge') {
    alert( "You've got the Edge!" );
  } else if (['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Opera', 'Safari'].includes(browser)) {
    alert( 'Okay we support these browsers too' )
  } else {
    alert( 'We hope that this page looks ok!' )
  }
```